# How to sample points uniformly over a region of the unit sphere

Tags: monte-carlo, random-sampling

I am looking for a way to sample points uniformly around a particular point on the unit sphere.

Working on spherical coordinates we can express any point on the unit sphere as $(\sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$. Say the initial point $r_0$ has coordinates $(\sin\theta_0 \cos\phi_0, \sin\theta_0\sin\phi_0,\cos\theta_0)$, I want to sample points uniformly over the solid angle of a cone around the initial point with an apex angle of $2\delta$ (see Figure below).

[image: Cone around arbitrary direction]

If the initial point is the north pole this is easy to do because $\phi$ can be taken uniformly as $2\pi \,\rm{rand}(0,1)$ and for $\theta$ the usual inverse transform method can be truncated to the desired range $(0,\delta]$ [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Truncated_distribution).

I don't know how to go around the general case though, I'd appreciate if anyone has some idea of how to attack this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing missing was performing a rotation afterwards to the north pole case. Check  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/generate-a-random-direction-within-a-cone for more details

Comment: If we want the points to be uniformly distributed on the surface, it is not the polar angle $\phi$ that should be uniformly distributed but $\cos(\phi)$.

Comment: Details are given in Brannon's book on rotations: https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-0-7503-1454-1/chapter/bk978-0-7503-1454-1ch17

Comment: Uniformly sample over the sphere, and then reject the samples outside your desired region.

Answer (score 1):

So if I correctly understand, you know how to sample in the "vertical" cone, and you ask how to rotate?

Here is some pseudo-code to get the unit quaternion representing a rotation sending a line directed by a vector `U` to a line directed by a vector `V`:

```
getTheQuaternion <- function(U, V){
  U <- normalize(U)
  V <- normalize(V)
  d <- dotproduct(U, V)
  c <- sqrt(1 + d)
  r <- 1 / sqrt(2) / c
  W <- r * crossproduct(U, V)
  quaternion <- (c/sqrt(2), W[1], W[2], W[3])
  return(quaternion)
}
```

and some pseudo-code to get the rotation matrix corresponding to a unit quaternion:

```
quaternion2matrix <- function(q){
  (
    (1 - 2*q[3]^2 - 2*q[4]^2, 2*q[2]*q[3] - 2*q[4]*q[1], 2*q[2]*q[4] + 2*q[3]*q[1]),
    (2*q[2]*q[3] + 2*q[4]*q[1], 1 - 2*q[2]^2 - 2*q[4]^2, 2*q[3]*q[4] - 2*q[2]*q[1]),
    (2*q[2]*q[4] - 2*q[3]*q[1], 2*q[3]*q[4] + 2*q[2]*q[1], 1 - 2*q[2]^2 - 2*q[3]^2)
  )
}
```